# Creating a simple, single-view Quartz app

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm an Objective-C newbie. Most of my experience is in Java. Also, I've never really used Xcode before and so I'm pretty new at that as well.

I'm trying to create a simple, single-view Quartz OS X app (not iOS) to display agent-modeling simulations. The graphics are pretty simple; just colored squares and grids. I have been looking at Quartz tutorials and I can see how I could accomplish this (as far as drawing things are concerned). What I can't find is an example that tells me how to tie it all together. What do I put in `AppDelegate`? Do I need a `WindowController`? How do I link that up with `AppDelegate`? I got as far as creating a Quartz Composer View in Interface Builder for my app, but I have no idea where to go from there.

As I mentioned before, I've looked for numerous tutorials but there is nothing that I can find that gives me information as far as linking everything together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should visit [this web page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html) before you do anything else. It will show you how a Cocoa application is structured and where the appropriate entry points are to place your code.

While the entire article merits reading, visit the section "Entry and Exit Points," which best addresses your particular questions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This definitely helps - there seems to be a lot of magic happening behind the scenes and this seems very helpful!